# Getting a return value from a methodInfo.invoke

Tags: invoke, methodinfo

How do I get a return value `(int)` from a `methodInfo.invoke`?

What makes it difficult for me is the fact that I use a string variable to call the method.

Check the example below:

```
if (Convert.ToBoolean(getParameterFromXML("issue", k, 1)) == true)
{
    m = k + 1;

    MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(frmDetails).GetMethod("Issue" + m);
    methodInfo.Invoke(this, Parameters);

}
```

What can I do? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

When I read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx) you get the result of the method back from the Invoke-call. It is returned as an object so you need to cast it to a specific type.

```
var returnValue = (int) methodInfo.Invoke(this, Parameters);
```