# Documenting Powershell modules and scripts

Tags: powershell, documentation

With [Powershell 5 introducing OOP Classes support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes?view=powershell-6), the traditional [comment-based](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comment_based_help?view=powershell-6) Powershell documentation methods for functions, scripts and modules are no longer a good fit. `Get-Help` is not presenting any help for classes, methods or properties and it looks like it will be staying that way. Other than that, Get-Help is not much of help when trying to find information on a specific function without actually having the module or powershell script in question.

As classes are especially useful for more complex Powershell projects, the need for an up-to-date documentation is more pressing than ever. Projects like [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/index.html) and the [Sandcastle Help File Builder](https://ewsoftware.github.io/SHFB/) do support help generation for a number of OO-languages, but do not seem to be able to handle Powershell code. A quick look at the [PoshBuild project](https://github.com/zanyants/PoshBuild) reveals that it is targeted at .NET language projects, too and needs to be integrated into the Visual Studio build process, which pure-Powershell code does not have.

There is also [PSDoc](https://chaseflorell.github.io/powershell/2015/04/27/how-to-generate-beautiful-powershell-documentation/) capable of generating documentation for modules in HTML or markdown formats based on Get-Help output, which would have been pretty much what I want if it supported classes.

So how do I auto-generate sensible documentation if I have

1. .ps1 scripts
2. .psm1 modules
3. classes in my Powershell code

using the comment-based help documentation syntax?

Comment: Why not just fork PsDoc and roll a custom solution for your classes? Or take a look at The Classy PlatyPS module, it has support for classes and enums: https://get-powershellblog.blogspot.com/2017/05/the-classy-platyps-automated-class-enum.html

Comment: I think I must have stumbled upon PSRAW's Classy PlatyPS somewhere in the past and have dismissed it for one reason or the other. But at a second glance it looks quite useful. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: No problem. Can you mark it as the answer if I post that as one?

Comment: @trebleCode sure, go on

Answer (score 1):

@trebleCode still deserves the answer, I'm just posting this for anyone interested.

I started trying to answer this question a while ago but got distracted and never finished. If I recall correctly, there was some discussion I found on Github where they said they didn't plan on supporting comment annotated classes, which is sad because I like Powershell Comments.

My thought here was that by calling the builtin help methods you could create a helper function that would detect these non-standard comments above the class keyword and convert them to comment objects without invoking `get-help`. These comments could also be stored in external files.

Below I found the code for parsing comments into objects and creating comment objects in code.

```
# References: 
# https://learn-powershell.net/2015/08/07/invoking-private-static-methods-using-powershell/
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259222/how-to-access-internal-class-using-reflection
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15652656/get-return-value-after-invoking-a-method-from-dll-using-reflection
# https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/a8627b83e5cea71c3576871eacad7f2b19826d53/src/System.Management.Automation/help/HelpCommentsParser.cs

$ExampleComment = @"
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    This was a triumph
#>
"@

$CommentLines = [Collections.Generic.List`1[String]]::new()
$InvokeArgs = @($ExampleComment, $CommentLines)

# GetMethod Filter
$BindingFlags = 'static','nonpublic','instance'

# GetMethod Filter: We need to specify overloaded methods by their parameters
$ParamTypes  = [Type]::GetTypeArray($InvokeArgs)
$ParamCount  = [System.Reflection.ParameterModifier]::new(2)

$HelpParser  = [psobject].Assembly.GetType('System.Management.Automation.HelpCommentsParser')
$CollectCommentText = $HelpParser.GetMethod('CollectCommentText', $BindingFlags, $null, $ParamTypes, $ParamCount)

# Extension methods aren't part of the class so null gets called first.
# TODO: Figure out return value
$CollectCommentText.Invoke($Null,$InvokeArgs)
$InvokeArgs

# Comment object but properties are read only.
$CommentHelp = [System.Management.Automation.Language.CommentHelpInfo]::new()
$CommentHelp.Synopsis
$CommentHelp.Description
$CommentHelp.Examples
$CommentHelp
```